# Out of memory exception occurred at Bitmap Shadder android

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapshader

I am working on android application in which i am using Bitmap, but the problem is that sometimes it shows me an error of out of memory and my application get crashed. I am using bitmaps along with BitmapShadder, my code is given below where my application shows this error.

```
public class CircularImageView extends ImageView {
private int borderWidth = 0;
private int viewWidth;
private int viewHeight;
private Bitmap image;
private Paint paint;
private Paint paintBorder;
private BitmapShader shader;

public CircularImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setup();
}

public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setup();
}

public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setup();
}

private void setup() {
    // init paint
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    paintBorder = new Paint();
    setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
    paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
    this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
    // paintBorder.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
}

public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
    this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    this.invalidate();
}

public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
    if (paintBorder != null)
        paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);

    this.invalidate();
}

private void loadBitmap() {
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) this.getDrawable();

    if (bitmapDrawable != null)
        image = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
}

// @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // load the bitmap
    loadBitmap();

    // init shader
    if (image != null) {

        // Out Of Memory Error Comes Here.... 

        shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image,canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), false),Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        int circleCenter = viewWidth / 2;

        // circleCenter is the x or y of the view's center
        // radius is the radius in pixels of the cirle to be drawn
        // paint contains the shader that will texture the shape
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter
                + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth - 4.0f,
                paintBorder);
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter
                + borderWidth, circleCenter - 4.0f, paint);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

    viewWidth = width - (borderWidth * 2);
    viewHeight = height - (borderWidth * 2);

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // Measure the text
        result = viewWidth;
    }

    return result;
}

private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight, int measureSpecWidth) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // Measure the text (beware: ascent is a negative number)
        result = viewHeight;
    }

    return (result + 2);
}
}
```

Comment: add exception block of outOfMemory Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your manifest application tag.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```